# Detect if power cable unplugged even when no power

Tags: android, detect

Is there a way to detect if the power cable gets unplugged even if it's not plugged into a power source?  For example, I plug in my phone to it's power cable prior to plugging it into the wall outlet.

I know you can detect power-state-change, but - I don't think there is a change to power state  when this happens.

I believe this exists for headphone jack, so I was hoping it would also be available for power jack.

(I realize this is probably a strange request)

Comment: strange, however interesting.

Comment: I'm opening up old wounds here but it might be interesting; [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/95578/33807) is a nice answer on how this works for the headphone jack. Unless a similar approach is done in a certain power connector (of which I'm not aware), you can't detect an un-powered cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to detect simple cable changes for the USB port.

You can detect power changes because, well, they cause a change in the power state of the device, and you can detect the electrical energy.

You can do this for headphone jacks because the jack itself completes a small circuit within the device (I think. I'm not an audio circuitry expert, so don't take my word for it).

Comment: I assume you're right, but am holding out in case.  Unless you found documentation somewhere that says it's non-detectable?  Thanks!